# Managing multiple pages with Marionette, Browserify & Gulp

Tags: backbone.js, gulp, marionette

I already managed to use Backbone, Marionette, Browserify & Gulp for different web-apps and usually relied on a single, bloated bundle.js... easy stuff, nowadays!

However, for a new project I would prefer having separate vendors/dependencies within one file (e.g. globals.js) and page specific routings, views and dependencies in another one (e.g. bookings.js / reservations.js / ...) to generally speed up my backend (delivered through CakePHP).

How would such an approach practically look like - does Browserify provide all the required features or are there other best practices in the JS-world?

Comment: Don't know best practice, but I can tell you what I have done. I use Grunt to manage attaching global stuff - styles, `View`s and other Backbone objects needed on many pages, and utility libraries. Then I manually add a single page-specific script to each page. This is a half-solution... it demands code is either one place or everywhere, not just-where-needed. But it's a step in the direction you are looking at.

Comment: Taking a closer look into gulp's tasks helped me a lot. That way I was able to create a task for each specific .js-file. Vendor's can be separated by using the externals() method. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485440/make-browserify-modules-external-with-gulp